# 501 error with baikal / calDAV

Tags: apache, caldav, sabre

I found some calDAV / sabre / baikal related questions and answers here at stackoverflow, so this might be the appropriate place for my question.

I set up a baikal-flat server at my domain, hosted at one.com.

My .htaccess lives at /baikal and looks like this

```
# Allow HTTP headers with Apache/FastCGI
# See http://code.google.com/p/sabredav/wiki/Authentication#Apache_+_(Fast)CGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive Off
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} baikal
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.<mydomain>.com/baikal/$1 [R,L]
```

Rewriting to ssl works now, I get https connections to baikal's web interface. Accessing it via korganizer, thunderbird and android fails - I tried any thinkable address combination. My first attempt was with
https://.com/baikal/cal.php/calendars//default/

I get a 501 error.

When I do

```
curl -so - --digest --user <username>:<password> https://<mydomain>.com/baikal/cal.php/calendars/<username>/default
```

for debugging, this is the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d:error xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://sabredav.org/ns">
<s:exception>Sabre\DAV\Exception\NotImplemented</s:exception>
<s:message>GET is only implemented on File objects</s:message>
<s:sabredav-version>1.8.7</s:sabredav-version>
</d:error>
```

I found google hits on that messages, but they seem to be iphone-related.

```
<username>, <mydomain> and <password>
```

is replaced by the real items without brackets in the real files. (-;
Could someone give me a hint?

Greetings,
Wolf

Answer (score 0):

This error message is expected. `GET` requests don't work by default on collections.

Try a `PROPFIND` request if you want to see a real response coming back.